# Increment through child arraylist in 2-d array to add every other element to a new array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, parent-child, nested-loops

I've looked all over for answer to this question and I haven't seen anything specifically stated about it.

I have written an arraylist of arraylists and I need to increment through all of the child lists to get every other element in the list. This is as close as I've come so far:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

int sz1=0; // how many questions in the new string array
int ctr=0; // increment through Question to set value of index

String [] Question = new String[sz1];

for(int x=0; x < list.size(); x++){

        sz1 = ((list.get(x).size() -1) / 2);


        for(int y=0; y < list.get(x).size(); y++){
            if ((y == 1) || (y % 2 == 1)){

                Question[ctr] = list.get(x).get(y); // throws Out of Bounds Exception: 0
                ctr++ // add 1 for the next index


            }
        }
    }
```

I think it might have something to do with the innerloop, but i haven't been able to figure it out for hours. I'm guessing the problem is the innerloop is calling for the size instead of the index, but I'm not sure how to correct that for a 2-d arraylist.

So ultimately, I'm trying to store every other string in each child arraylist of the parent arraylist into a new string array.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

**Update**
Thank very much for the input thus far, here is all the code I have for this. To try to answer some of the questions brought up, As far as I know, the list seems to populate correctly. Also, the input to the 'list array' is a text file. the first line in each 'category' is the category name, then question and answer. Each category is separated by a blank line. i.e.:
category
question
answer

new category
...
...

I have all of that figured out, so now i need to grab each question and answer in its own arraylist (as @icyitscold pointed out, thank you), I tried to keep it simple by only showing the loops im working on but it's probably best to show all of it so you can see what's going on (as @Dukeling pointed out.).

So here's the code:

```
`public void Read_File() throws FileNotFoundException{

File infile = new File("trivia.txt");

    String line = "";

    Scanner sr = new Scanner(infile);
    int i=0;


    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


    ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();


    while (sr.hasNext()){
        i++;


        list.add(new ArrayList<String>());

        while (sr.hasNext()){       // Reads one whole category

            line = sr.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(line);

            if (line.length() == 0)
                {break;}

            list.get(i-1).add(line); // add line to the array list in that position

        }   
        System.out.println(list);

            }


    String [] catName  = new String[6];
for(int x=0; x < list.size(); x++){                 // category array
        catName[x] = list.get(x).get(0);}

    for(int x=0; x < list.size(); x++){             // questions array

        for(int y=0; y < list.get(x).size(); y++){
            if ((y == 1) || (y % 2 == 1)){
                question.add(list.get(x).get(y));   // throws OB of 0

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(question);

    sr.close(); 

}`
```

Comment: The OOB exception is from Question array, which is initialized with size 0

Comment: @nitegazer2003 If we were to take the code at face value, the list is also empty, thus the for-loop won't execute.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the missing code that adds items to the list and increments `sz1`. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I was able to correctly understand what you're looking for... You had a couple of problems with your code snippet. First, you were initializing your "Question" array with a size of zero - that was causing your Out of Bounds exception - once you specify an Array's size, you cannot change it. That is why I used an ArrayList instead of an a String[] in my snippet. ArrayLists are nicer because don't have to worry about the dimensions of the underlying Array, it expands for you.

Also note how I changed the variable named "Question" to "question" - In java, variable names should start with a lower case letter. Per the [Oracle Code Conventions document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367):

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first letter

Assuming that `list` is populated correctly, this code should work:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int x=0; x < list.size(); x++){

        for(int y=0; y < list.get(x).size(); y++){
            if ((y == 1) || (y % 2 == 1)){

                question.add(list.get(x).get(y));

            }
        }
    }
```

The resulting `question` ArrayList should have every second String as specified.

Comment: If we were to take the code at face value, the list is also empty, thus the for-loop won't execute, thus we'd never get to the line causing the exception. We don't know how large `Question` is. It's too small, but we can't say much beyond that.

Comment: That is true, but with my solution, we never need to know how large `Question` is - thus, it should help the OP.